# How to process the JSON data using .getJSON

Tags: getjson

My business functionality is to format JSON code returned from database and then use AJAX to process the JSON content and need to use only ".getJSON" instead of ".ajax"

The point where i was struck up is: how to sent the parameters using .getJSON to another page (customer.php) as i need to search for the customer data from database and return result in JSON formate.[The "data"  parameter which holds key&value pair that needs to be sent to the server.]

Code from ajaxcall.php(where .getJSON is used)

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
function search(){
            var x=$("#srh").val();
             if(x!=""){

  $.getJSON({
              url:'/customer.php',
              data:{value:"x"},
              success:function (data)
               {
                content= data;
                $("#result").html(content[0].cust_id);      
               }
             });
             }
             }

             $("#button").click(function(){
                     search();
                  });
            });
</script>       
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="srh" placeholder="Enter the Name of the Customer"/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="search" />

<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Here, i need to pass the X parameter to customer.php using getJSON.The way i am passing is not working!

Code from customer.php(where i need to get search term (X parameter as input)   $var=$_POST["value"] 
and fetch the data from database using X parameter in where condition and return data in JSON content)

```
<?php
      $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "xyz", "12345", "cust");
    $var=$_GET['value'];  

        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {          echo 'connect not possible to database: ' . mysqli_connect_error($conn);      }
    else
    {
        $query="SELECT cust_fname,cust_lname,cust_id,cust_addresa,cust_phone
       from customer where UPPER(cust_lname) like UPPER('%" . $x. "%') "; 

         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if (!$result) {   die("Not Found ! " . mysqli_error($conn));  }
        else 
        {   
         $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $json = json_encode($rows); 

        }
         mysqli_free_result($result);
         mysqli_close($conn);
         print $json;       

}
 } ?>
```

Appreciate your pointer on this! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it possible that you are assigning ```$var``` to the value of the parameter and then using ```$x``` in the query argument where you should be using ```$var```?

Comment: Its a typo mistake, i am using $var in query.

Comment: Please fix the typo in the examples. This will help me or anyone else who sees this question better determine the problem. Also can you explain in what way it is not working?